# Autoscale with margin in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

In order to have a plot with autoscale axes with matplotlib, I use this code:

```
axes.set_autoscale_on(True)
axes.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
```

It works well, and I have this plot:
[image: My plot]

But I'd like to have a margin on the top, i.e. in my example I'd like the y axe goes up to 11 instead of 10. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try following code:

```
axes.set_autoscale_on(True)
axes.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
axes.set_ylim(0, 11) # 11 -> max(yvalues) + 1
```

Comment: Would you know a way to do that programmatically, without searching for the max of the values of the serie? This has been computed in `matplotlib`, and I find no way to recover it...