# Python: Add x-y margins automatically with autoscale (pyplot)

Tags: python, matplotlib

A similar question asked here 
[Autoscale with margin in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611051/autoscale-with-margin-in-matplotlib)

[image]

so I don't like the fact the frame of the figure and histogram bars touch each other. The solution given is:

```
axes.set_ylim(0, 11)
```

good, it works, but I have many figures and every time I only want a 10% margin. So manually it is a difficult thing, is there a way to set margin both in x-axis and y-axis?

I need something like `subplots_adjust`, but for the inner, data area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if there a way to do this using matplotlib functions but you could always define your own, the following works for me:

```
def inner_subplots_adjust(axes, xmargin=0.1, ymargin = 0.1):
    xmin, xmax = axes.get_xbound()
    ymin, ymax = axes.get_ybound()
    xscale = 1 + xmargin
    yscale = 1 + ymargin
    axes.set_xbound((xmin*xscale, xmax*xscale))
    axes.set_ybound((ymin*yscale, ymax*yscale))
```